# Partial intersection of elements across vectors in two lists

Tags: r, list, match, intersection

I have a list like this:

```
mylist <- list(PP = c("PP 1", "OMITTED"),
           IN01 = c("DID NOT PARTICIPATE", "PARTICIPATED", "OMITTED"),                     
           RD1 = c("YES", "NO", "NOT REACHED", "INVALID", "OMITTED"),
           RD2 = c("YES", "NO", "NOT REACHED", "NOT AN OPTION", "OMITTED"),
           LOS = c("LESS THAN 3", "3 TO 100", "100 TO 500", "MORE THAN 500", "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE", "OMITTED"),
           COM = c("BAN", "SBAN", "RAL"), 
           VR1 = c("WITHIN 30", "WITHIN 200", "NOT AVAILABLE", "OMITTED"),                         
           INF = c("A LOT", "SOME", "LITTLE OR NO", "NOT APPLICABLE", "OMITTED"),               
           IST = c("FULL-TIME", "PART-TIME", "FULL STAFFED", "NOT STAFFED", "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE", "OMITTED"),
           CMP = c("ALL", "MOST", "SOME", "NONE", "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE", "OMITTED"))
```

I have another list like this:

```
matchlist <- list("INVALID", c("INVALID", "OMITTED OR INVALID"),
c("INVALID", "OMITTED"), "OMITTED", c("NOT REACHED", "INVALID", "OMITTED"),
c("LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE", "INVALID", "OMITTED"),
c("LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE", "INVALID", "OMITTED OR INVALID"),
c("Not applicable", "Not stated"), c("Not reached", "Not administered/missing by design", "Presented but not answered/invalid"),
c("Not administered/missing by design", "Presented but not answered/invalid"),
"OMITTED OR INVALID",
c("LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE", "OMITTED OR INVALID"),
c("NOT REACHED", "OMITTED"),
c("NOT APPLICABLE", "OMITTED"), 
c("LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE", "OMITTED"),
c("LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE", "NOT REACHED", "OMITTED"),
"NOT EXCLUDED", c("Default", "Not applicable", "Not stated"), c("Valid Skip", "Not Reached", "Not Applicable", "Invalid", "No Response"),
c("Not administered", "Omitted"),
c("NOT REACHED", "INVALID RESPONSE", "OMITTED"),
c("INVALID RESPONSE", "OMITTED"))
```

As you can see, some of the vectors in `matchlist` partially match vectors in `mylist`. In some cases the vectors in `matchlist` have exact match with part of vectors in `mylist`. For example, the last values of `RD1` in `mylist` match the vector in the fifth component of `matchlist`, but `RD2` does not match it, although common values are present. The values in `RD2` in `mylist` ("NOT REACHED", "NOT AN OPTION", "OMITTED") **together and in this order** do not have a match in any of the vectors in `matchlist`. It is the same for the values of `COM` in `mylist`.

What I am trying to achieve is to compare the elements in each vector in `mylist` against each vector in `matchlist`, extract the values that are common and match the values in `matchlist` **in the same order**, and store them in another list. The desired result shall look like this:

```
$PP
[1] "OMITTED"

$IN01
[1] "OMITTED"

$RD1
[1] "NOT REACHED" "INVALID" "OMITTED"

$RD2
character(0)

$LOS
[1] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"

$COM
character(0)

$VR1
[1] "OMITTED"

$INF
[1] "NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"

$IST
[1] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"

$CMP
[1] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
```

What I tried so far:

Using `intersect`

```
lapply(mylist, function(i) {
  intersect(i, lapply(matchlist, function(i) {i}))
})
```

It returns only the last value in each vector of `matchlist` ("OMITTED").

Using `match` through `%in%`:

```
lapply(mylist, function(i) {
  i[which(i %in% matchlist)]
})
```

Returns the desired result only for `RD1` ("INVALID", "OMITTED"), for the rest it returns just the last value ("OMITTED"), except for `COM` which is correct.

Using `mapply` and `intersect`:

```
mapply(intersect, mylist, matchlist)
```

Returns a long list with mixture of pretty much everything, including combinations that should not be there, plus a warning for the unequal lengths.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: With `RD1` as an example, what are your expectations when you have multiple matches, the longest one (by vector length)? `mapply` is not what you want here, it does `intersect(mylist[[1]], matchlist[[1]])`, then `intersect(mylist[[2]], matchlist[[2]])`, etc.

Comment: @r2evans - not sure I understand, but the strings in `mylist` should match entire vector in `matchlist`. That is, values in `RD1` should match the fifth vector in `mylist` only (`c("NOT REACHED", "INVALID", "OMITTED")`) and nothing else.

Comment: `RD1` matches one word each from `matchlist` indices 1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 15, and 22; it matches two words each from 3, 6, 13, 16, and 21; and three words from 5. It "seems obvious" that you want the longest of those, is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some really simple/good answers, but they all seem to rely on `unlist`. I'm assuming that you need to preserve the grouping within `matchlist`, so unlisting them does not make sense. Here's a solution that works without that, using a double-`lapply` loop as you started to do:

```
out <- lapply(mylist, function(this) {
  mtch <- lapply(matchlist, intersect, this)
  wh <- which.max(lengths(mtch))
  if (length(wh)) mtch[[wh]] else character(0)
})
str(out)
# List of 9
#  $ PP  : chr "OMITTED"
#  $ IN01: chr "OMITTED"
#  $ RD1 : chr [1:3] "NOT REACHED" "INVALID" "OMITTED"
#  $ LOS : chr [1:2] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
#  $ COM : chr(0) 
#  $ VR1 : chr "OMITTED"
#  $ INF : chr [1:2] "NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
#  $ IST : chr [1:2] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
#  $ CMP : chr [1:2] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
```

It always returns a vector with the most number of matches, but if there are (somehow) more than one, I think it will preserve the natural order and return the first of said long-matches. (The question there is: *"does `which.max` preserve natural order?"* I think it does but have not verified.)

***UPDATE***

The constraint was added that not only the presence and order of the `matchlist` vectors was required, but also that there are no interloping words. For instance, if as suggested in the comments, `mylist$RD1` has `"BLAH"`, then it will not longer match with `matchlist[[5]]`.

Checking for a perfectly-ordered subset of one vector to another is a bit more problematic (and therefore not a code-golf champion), and often scales poorly because we don't have easy subset determination. With that caveat, this implementation does some nested `*apply` functions ...

(NB: it was suggested in a comment that `$RD1` should return `character(0)`, but it does have `"INVALID"` which matches one of the single-length components of `matchlist`, so it should match, just not the longer one.)

```
out <- lapply(mylist, function(this) {
  ind <- lapply(matchlist, function(a) which(this == a[1]))
  perfectmatches <- mapply(function(ml, allis, this) {
    length(ml) * any(sapply(allis, function(i) all(ml == this[ i + seq_along(ml) - 1 ])))
  }, matchlist, ind, MoreArgs = list(this=this))
  if (any(perfectmatches) > 0) {
    wh <- which.max(perfectmatches)
    return(matchlist[[wh]])
  } else return(character(0))
})
str(out)
# List of 9
#  $ PP  : chr "OMITTED"
#  $ IN01: chr "OMITTED"
#  $ RD1 : chr "INVALID"
#  $ LOS : chr [1:2] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
#  $ COM : chr(0) 
#  $ VR1 : chr "OMITTED"
#  $ INF : chr [1:2] "NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
#  $ IST : chr [1:2] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
#  $ CMP : chr [1:2] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
```

Comment: Try `mylist <- list(A = 1:3); matchlist <- list(1, 2:3)`; then `out` gives only `2 3`. I doubt that that's the expected output.

Comment: That's one way my interpretation of the question differs from yours, and it's an intentional difference. Ultimately I do not know, perhaps panman will come back with some clarification.

Comment: Sorry, was out of the office. Actually I owe an apology to everyone, the question was probably not formulated well. Try to change `RD1` in `mylist` to `c("YES", "NO", "NOT REACHED", "BLAH", "INVALID", "OMITTED")`. Then the result should return `character(0)` because it has no match of its values **in the same order** in any of the vectors in `matchlist`, as the question states. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need to edit your question and add that constraint, as I feel it is easy to assume the presence of interlopers (`"BLAH"`) are not problematic.

Comment: Thank you r2evans, I have edited the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time and effort, this really helps a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution using `unlist` with `matchlist`:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x %in% unlist(matchlist)])
```

Output (new list):

```
$PP
[1] "OMITTED"

$IN01
[1] "OMITTED"

$RD1
[1] "NOT REACHED" "INVALID"     "OMITTED"    

$LOS
[1] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"                 

$COM
character(0)

$VR1
[1] "OMITTED"

$INF
[1] "NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"       

$IST
[1] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"                 

$CMP
[1] "LOGICALLY NOT APPLICABLE" "OMITTED"
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! Can you please explain why unlisting `matchlist` works in this case, I am not sure I understand it, it produces a single vector from `matchlist`.

Comment: Using `?unlist` should help! Given a list, it will return a single vector with all individual components on the list. You can then apply `%in%` that returns a logic vector indicating which components of the first vector are in the second (which is the unlisted list).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation too.

Answer (score 3):

Writing simply

```
lapply(mylist, intersect, unlist(matchlist))
```

also works.

Comment: wow, that really took the OPs ideas to a working and short solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I already asked Carles Mitjans, can you please explain why unlisting `matchlist` works in this case, I am not sure I understand it, it produces a single vector from `matchlist`.

Comment: As Charles told you: type `?unlist` into R console. Read it. Then do the Examples at the end of the Info. Reading and understanding the manual is how you get a pro in R.

Comment: To add to that, @panman, I think that, given the expected output, your problem currently is described in a slightly confusing manner and could be stated differently, showing clearly why `unlist` is the way to go. You only care which elements in `mylist[[i]]` exist somewhere in `matchlist`, meaning that there is no need to count the number of occurrences (hence `intersect`) or keep track of their place in `matchlist` (hence `unlist`). The order is also preserved by `intersect`.

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(mylist, function(i) {
  unlist(sapply(i,function(x){if(any(grepl(paste0("^",x,"$"),matchlist))){x}}))
})
```

I added the "\b" before and after the string because of the "NO" that can lead to finding "NOT". Using grepl is surely not the best way as the other answer show :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is an interesting solution.

Comment: adding `\\b` is not good enough. You should add `^` and `$` arround. (Besides the fact this solution is impressive but inferior to the others.)

Comment: @AndreElrico thank you, indeed I should add these two. And yes clearly inferior, but still i though it was worth it

Comment: It's absolutely worth it!  `\\b` should be REPLACED by `^` and `$` respectively. Otherwise `"\\bNO\\b"` would match `"RAND NO RAND"`.